# Finding out how many files are in a folder and then writing that number to a ListView in android

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to work this right. I have never used .length on anything other then files but now I'm trying to find out how many files are in a folder and put that into a list view for android. I'll be getting all the names of those files and putting those in there later but I got stuck at this part. Anyway here is my code

```
private void fileFinder() {
    int x = new File(<"C:/Users/Mike Home/Desktop/test">).listFiles().length;
//      int x = 12;

//      for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
//          files[i] = Integer.toString(i);
//      }

    files[0] = Integer.toString(x);
}
```

Could it be my string?

```
    String[] files = new String[]{

};
```

Would I need to tell it how many strings to make?

However if I try to get a specific file name it works so I know my folder is working.

```
    File hello = new File ("C:/Users/Mike Home/Desktop/test/mike.txt");
    files[0]=hello.getName();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. There is no file "C:/Users/Mike home/Desktop/test" on an Android device. Are you trying to read your development system's hard drive from within an Android app? That's not going to work.

Comment: <"C:/Users/Mike Home/Desktop/test"> for your info android is based on Linux not Windows..

Comment: @Ted Hopp Yes I'm reading my own hard drive. It seems to be working fine. All the code I have in here is pretty much java. maybe .length is just not working. But if I do `File hello = new File ("C:/Users/Mike Home/Desktop/test/mike.txt"); files[0]=hello.getName();` it works just fine.

Comment: @Mike - That will work because you haven't actually read anything from the hard drive. It would work if you used `"NASA://SpaceShuttle/TheEnd" as the file name. (Try getting its last modified time, or size, or anything else that actually requires going to the file. You'll see the difference.)

Comment: Ohh I see. So I'll be mounting a drive to the android devise then. That sounds like my next logical step. Or you know what I'll try to do this in a java app first then port it over to android. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the file system of the host OS that is running the emulator. You cannot directly connect to the Windows file system from a device, either. Perhaps there's an app that communicates with a server application running on Windows that allows this. You're going to have to set up something like that yourself if accessing the C: drive is what you want to do.

Comment: Just more work then I thought it was. I was hoping I could use the c: drive as a quick folder to test my function. I have quite a bit more steps to get through before I can get to this one.

Answer (score 0):

This line:
`int n = new File("C:/Users/Mike Home/Desktop/test").listFiles().length;`

is enough. It just finds you the number of files in your folder. That's it. Now show this number where you want. Your call `Integer.toString(x)` seems irrelevant anyway. Primitives in java are being translated to string automatically.

Comment: @AlexR - The last part, "Primitives in java are being translated to string automatically" is wrong. For instance, you cannot do this: `String x = 3;`. They are only "translated" to strings in expressions like `"n=" + 3`, but the compiler does that by turning it into a call to StringBuilder.append(int).

Comment: Here is the most annoying part. Wait for it.... 
`File hello = new File ("C:/Users/Mike Home/Desktop/test/mike.txt");

     files[0]=hello.getName();`
Works just fine.

Comment: @Mike - That works because it requires no access to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a complete solution? If so, I think this article can help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895104/file-browser-in-android

In your specific code snippet, I think you just shouldn't be using a DOS volume descriptor. Try [android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html).

Comment: Wow this looks in depth. I'll have to check this out tomorrow. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Sparky - That isn't going to work. `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns a File object pointing to the SDCard or similar mass storage (if any) on the device. This is true of the emulator as well; it just won't allow direct interaction with the file system of the host OS in which the emulator is running.